# Can anyone hint at a way to recall my iterated labels in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

This is my first question here and i am not a programmer by trade, i build machines and sometimes use programming to do secondary adjustments. This is part of a modbus HMI project in python. I create switches and labels iteratively but after that i cant reach their properties. As i said this was written with kivy, but no important kv code was used, just positioning.

```
class InputGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 8
        self.indicators=mp.readInputs(qty=48)
        self.red = (1, 0, 0, 1)
        self.green = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateLabels,1)
        for i in range(0,48):
            self.l = Label(text="input " + str(i+1))
            if self.indicators[i] == False:
                self.l.color=self.red
            elif self.indicators[i] == True:
                self.l.color = self.green
            self.add_widget(self.l,i) #When i put in the index number self.ljust changes position...

    def updateLabels(self,dt):
        self.indicators=mp.readInputs(qty=48)
        self.l.color = self.green #Here i want to be able to change all 48 label colors...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a list of the `Labels`. For example, use `self.labels`:

```
class InputGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.labels = []
        self.cols = 8
        self.indicators=mp.readInputs(qty=48)
        self.red = (1, 0, 0, 1)
        self.green = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateLabels,1)
        for i in range(0,48):
            self.l = Label(text="input " + str(i+1))
            self.labels.append(self.l)
            if self.indicators[i] == False:
                self.l.color=self.red
            elif self.indicators[i] == True:
                self.l.color = self.green
            self.add_widget(self.l,i) #When i put in the index number self.ljust changes position...

    def updateLabels(self,dt):
        self.indicators=mp.readInputs(qty=48)
        for l in self.labels:
            l.color = self.green #Here i want to be able to change all 48 label colors...
```

Comment: I feel like i should have known that... Thanks a lot.